# How to Pass customer Details into Salesforce from Website

Tags: liveagent

I am working **Salesforce Live Agent and Using a Custom Chat Window** and NOT USING PRE CHAT FORM.

I want to pass: Email Address or User Id , to search a Contact record and then display the contact record and create a new case.

In my HTML page , I am doing below :

```
liveagent.addCustomDetail('Contact E-mail', 'test@test.com'); 


    liveagent.findOrCreate('Contact')
            .map('Email','Contact E-mail',true,true,true)
            .map('FirstName','First Name',false,false,true)
            .map('LastName','Last Name',false,false,true);

    liveagent.findOrCreate('Contact')
            .saveToTranscript('ContactId')
            .showOnCreate()
            .linkToEntity('Case','ContactId');

    // Set case details
    liveagent.addCustomDetail('Case Status','New');
    liveagent.addCustomDetail('Case Origin','Chat');
    liveagent.addCustomDetail('Case Record Type','012D0000ABCDXYZ');

    liveagent.findOrCreate('Case')
            .map('Status','Case Status',true,false,true)
            .map('Origin','Case Origin',false,false,true)
            .map('RecordType','Case Record Type',false,false,true)         
            .saveToTranscript('CaseId').showOnCreate()
```

But no Case is creating and no contact record is opening although I have a `contact.Email = test@test.com`

Please advise.

Thanks
Sumanth

Comment: Try removing :
 .map('FirstName','First Name',false,false,true)
  .map('LastName','Last Name',false,false,true);

Because you are not adding firstname and last name in custom detail